# Interfacing Arduino uno with lcd, keypad, gsm sim900A and GPS

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm, lcd, keypad

I have developed two codes but while combining both of them is not giving me the desired result.
The following code correctly displays the text message input of keypad on the LCD and prints it perfectly as a text message.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>  // serial software library for interfacing gsm module
SoftwareSerial Serial1(2, 3); // RX, TX  // connect gsm Tx at D2 and Rx at D3

#include<LiquidCrystal.h>     // LCD library for interfacing LCD
LiquidCrystal lcd(14,15,16,17,18,19);   // connect rs,en,d4,d5,d6,d7 respectevely

int i=0;

#include <Keypad.h>               // keypad library for interfacing keypad
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
int x=0;
int y=0;
int n=0;
int minValue=0;
int maxValue=0;
char keyPress=0;
int keyPressTime=100;
String msg="";

char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = 
{
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {11, 10, 9, 8}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {7, 6, 5, 4}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); 

String alpha="1!@_$%? ABC2 DEF3 GHI4 JKL5 MNO6 PQRS7 TUV8 WXYZ9 *  0# ";  

void setup() 
{
  Serial1.begin(9600);    // init serial1 for GSM
  lcd.begin(16,2);        // init LCD
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Initializing GSM");
  delay(2000);

  /*Serial1.print("\r"); 
  delay(1000);*/
  Serial1.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(1000);
  Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=\"+91**********\"\r");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Wallet Ready");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop()
{
  int n=0;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.noCursor();
  while(1)
  {
    lcd.cursor();
    char key = customKeypad.getKey();
    if(key=='1')
      getkey(0, 7, key);

     if(key=='2')
      getkey(8, 12, key);

     else if(key=='3')
      getkey(13, 17, key); 

     else if(key=='4')
      getkey(18, 22, key);

    else if(key=='5')
      getkey(23, 27, key);

    else if(key=='6')
      getkey(28, 32, key);

    else if(key=='7')
      getkey(33, 38, key);

    else if(key=='8')
      getkey(39,43, key);

    else if(key=='9')
      getkey(44, 49, key);

    else if(key=='*')
      getkey(50, 51, key);

    else if(key=='0')
      getkey(52, 54, key);

    else if(key=='#')
      getkey(55, 56, key);

    else if(key == 'C')
    {
         x--;
         lcd.setCursor(x,y);
         lcd.print(" ");
         n--;
         msg[n]=' '; 
         lcd.setCursor(x,y);
    }

    else if(key == 'D')
    {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.noBlink();
      lcd.print("Sending Data");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("To Phone");

      /*Serial1.print("\r"); 
      delay(1000);*/
      Serial1.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
      delay(1000);
      Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=\"+91**********\"\r");
      delay(1000);
      Serial1.println(msg);
      delay(1000);
      Serial1.write(0x1A);
      delay(1000);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd_status();
       //  clearmsg();
       n=0;
       i=0;
       x=0;
       y=0;
       msg="";
    }
  }
}

void getkey(int minValue, int maxValue, char keyPress)
{
   int ch=minValue;
   int pressed=1;
   char key=keyPress;
   lcd.noBlink();
   for(int i=0;i<keyPressTime;i++)
   {     
      if(key==keyPress)
      {
         lcd.setCursor(x,y);
         lcd.print(alpha[ch]);
         ch++;
         if(ch>maxValue)
         ch=minValue;
         i=0;   
      }
      key=customKeypad.getKey();
      delay(10);
    }

     if(pressed)
     {  
        x++;
        msg+=alpha[ch-1];
        n++;
        if(x>15)
        {
          x=0;
          y=1;
        }
     }
    pressed=0;
    lcd.blink();
}

void lcd_status()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Transaction Sent");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Successfully");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
}
```

And this code gives me correct GPS location value stored in the string Message.

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/*
   This sample sketch demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS++ (TinyGPSPlus) object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   9600-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 12(rx) and 13(tx).
*/
static const int RXPin = 12, TXPin = 13;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
boolean sent = false;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);
String message="";
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);

}

void loop()
{
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.
   if (ss.available()>0 && sent == false){
   if (gps.encode(ss.read())){
    displayInfo();
    if(message!=""){
   Serial.print(message);
   sent=true;
    }
  }
 }
}
void displayInfo()
{
 if (gps.location.isValid())
  {
    String lati=String(gps.location.lat(), 4);
    String longi=String(gps.location.lng(), 4);
    message="location: "+lati+","+longi+"\n";  
  }
}
```

But the issue comes when I am trying to combine the two codes such that I get the correct keypad input and GPS location on printing the text message through GSM module.